# Is there a way to combine multiple blocks into a single block so that it can be saved as reusable?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I like how the columns block works because it supports nesting. What I'm trying to do is similar to making the column block support 1 column (which you can force it to do, but it doesn't size correctly. This way, the entire block of multiple blocks and block types can be saved as a single reusable block instance.

Is this an instance where I need to start working on my own custom block type? Or will this be supported at some point?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [InnerBlock](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/editor/src/components/inner-blocks). You can basically, group couple of blocks into a single custom block.

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/editor';

registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/my-block', {
    // ...

    edit( { className } ) {
        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                <InnerBlocks />
            </div>
        );
    },

    save() {
        return (
            <div>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    }
} );
```

Btw, this is the main focus of Gutenberg Phase 2 development. And, Gutenberg will slowly take over into template building process.

Comment: I wish I could just jump into this, but I'm still quite new to this JSX thing. Thanks for helping me get my feet wet.

Comment: Start with Wes Bos - JS30 (It's a free course) then Follow Travesty Media Vanilla JS projects on YouTube. And then get your hand dirty on React. You keep at it and eventually you'll learn the Gutenberg way, Good luck :)